# How do I mock or fake behavior of a website to allow unit testing for certain JS functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

**Situation:**
I just started to learn unit testing my JavaScript code and I am wondering if there is a way to fake the behavior of the application in order to test certain cases. I read about sinon.js spy/stub/mock. However, as usual for JS there are plenty of further scripts and combinations (i.e. with mocha, chai, karma-jasmine) and I hope that somebody can tell me about a best practice.

**Let´s take an example:** 
If I want to test a function in a test runner, which changes the background-size in dependence of the window size, it is complicated to trigger different window sizes (not element sizes) in order to see the background-size adjustment working in multiple dimensions.

I already tested a few things, such as

```
var resizeW = sinon.stub($.prototype, 'width').returns(600);
var resizeH = sinon.stub($.prototype, 'height').returns(1600);

// no effect - always takes the original view.height/width
viewport.setAttribute("content", "height=" + viewheight + "px, width=" + viewwidth + "px, initial-scale=1.0"); 

// new window is not testable in the root testrunner window
window.open + window.resizeTo() / window.resizeBy() 

// shows no effect
window.innerHeight = '120'; window.innerWidth = '500';

// provides no possibility to assume different dimensions
$(window).trigger('resize');

// provides no possibility to assume different dimensions
$(document).trigger('resize');

// provides no possibility to assume different dimensions
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Using an iframe will be tedious, i.e. through conflicts with the CSS and jQuery between original HTML and testrunner HTML.

I hope somebody can suggest a convenient way to achieve this.

Comment: It is a bad example to use window resize as CSS media queries handle all of these calculations for you. IOE no need for any JavaScript.

Comment: Not really. Let´s assume the keyboard on a smartphone pops-up on textarea click and shrinks the entire content to the remaining window size - here you need an adjustment of the content, which is easier to handle with js. It is also superior, when you need continous adjustment of content rather than stepwise...

Comment: Have you tried: Selenium web driver http://www.seleniumhq.org 
or 
Headless Chrome https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

Comment: @jeff is right in most cases here, I'd say, partially due to the fact that CSS handles this in a different thread, vs. reacting to the `resize` event gets run in the same thread as the rest of the app, causing performance to suffer, oftentimes noticeably.

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing is intended to assert that the logic and state bits of your application work as expected.

While surely you can set up an unit testing suite to assert against your application presentation layer in the browser, probably is not the way to go, since as you're aware, **is pretty difficult to mock some browser behaviors**.

As @SteveB suggests in his comment, tools for end-to-end testing may suite you better than unit testing. Such tools allow to running your live application in the browser and make some assertions, while directly controlling the browser behavior, so you don't have bad times mocking jQuery's methods or even using it.

[Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/), [nightmare.js](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) are common tools to perform end-to-end testing.

Another tool that may suite you is [Quixote](https://github.com/jamesshore/quixote/blob/master/README.md), a tool for css assertions.

Sometimes, when working on front-end code, mocking native browser api's is mandatory even when unit-testing basic bits of functionality: in such cases, [writing tight functions](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Writing-Testable-JavaScript.html) is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though what you *really* care about is how your application integrates with the browser, not necessarily logic that you control yourself. This seems like an integration test, and in that case, you wouldn't want to stub out the browser functionality. In that case, some of the testing frameworks that others have mentioned like Selenium might be a good way to go (I might also suggest Puppeteer, which has a [setViewport](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport) function).

It's also possible to write this as a unit test if you externalize your dependencies, *if there is internal logic worth testing in isolation*, by passing the width and height into your code and verifying that your code responds appropriately, but it sounds as though the logic here is mostly around integrating with the browser/jQuery/DOM.

With regard to best practices, one important maxim to remember and explore is [**don't mock code that you don't own**](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own) - if you do, you're mocking behavior you don't control and could change out from under you, as well as possibly allowing your implementation to leak into your tests.